# Dockerfile - Mount host directory - copy a tar fie and run it - Error

Tags: centos, tar, docker

Please find below the docker file contents -

```
FROM centostaryum
MAINTAINER karthik.jayaraman
VOLUME ["/DockerFiles/Tomcat/tar"]
ADD /tar/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz /tmp
RUN ls /tmp
RUN tar -tzf /tmp/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz -C /opt
EXPOSE  8080
CMD service tomcat7 start
```

It gives me the following error

```
    Step 0 : FROM centostaryum
     ---> 175c30b6dbd7
    Step 1 : MAINTAINER karthik.jayaraman 
     ---> Running in 8872c0c61735
     ---> d16323a6931a
    Removing intermediate container 8872c0c61735
    Step 2 : VOLUME ["/DockerFiles/Tomcat/tar"]
     ---> Running in 829a35f36b3f
     ---> 74314abbc28e
    Removing intermediate container 829a35f36b3f
    Step 3 : ADD /tar/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz /tmp
     ---> 07a0bc6713ab
    Removing intermediate container 3af17fba511a
    Step 4 : RUN ls /tmp
     ---> Running in 113ed759c156
    apache-tomcat-7.0.47
     ---> 6fd41ed2fb76
    Removing intermediate container 113ed759c156
    Step 5 : RUN tar -tzf /tmp/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz -C /opt
     ---> Running in 08e4d0a1f30a
    tar (child): /tmp/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
    tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
    tar: Child returned status 2
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
    2014/06/13 18:25:32 The command [/bin/sh -c tar -tzf /tmp/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz -C /opt] returned a non-
    zero code: 2
```

The list command from the temp directory in the container lists the tomcat file but i am not sure what is wrong with the tar command.

I would appreciate some help in figuring out this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation on the ADD command](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add):

> If  is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format
>   (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory.
>   Resources from remote URLs are not decompressed. When a directory is
>   copied or unpacked, it has the same behavior as tar -x: the result is
>   the union of:
>
> - whatever existed at the destination path and
> - the contents of the source tree, with conflicts resolved in favor of "2." on a
>     file-by-file basis.

You can just `ADD` the file to `/opt` directly and it will do what you want. More explicitly, just do this:

`ADD /tar/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz /opt`

Comment: Just now figured that out. Was about to update it. Thanks for your response

Comment: But i use the same technique to copy a configuration file to init.d directory with the following command

ADD /files/scripts/tomcat /etc/init.d
RUN cd /etc/init.d
RUN chmod 755 tomcat

But with the first step itself, it hangs and does not give out any logs or errors. Am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash to `/etc/init.d/`

Comment: Tried that - Did not work. Does it has something to do with Superuser permissions ?

Comment: I cannot see any reason why it would hang if the source file exists and the destination directory exists. Try using the full path, `/etc/init.d/tomcat`. Also, the next two commands will not quite work. Just use `RUN chmod 755 /etc/init.d/tomcat` instead.

Answer (score 1):

RUN  yum -y update && \ yum -y install wget && \ yum install -y tar.x86_64 && \
    yum clean all